# Delay on a RTSP livestream to an android device

Tags: android, video-streaming, delay, rtsp

Recently I've created an app that recieves a RTSP livestream(in mp4 format) from an ffserver using SurfaceView and MediaPlayer, however the delay between the input to the server and the video displayed on the screen is about 4 seconds, which is far to long for the purpose of my application. I'd appreciate it if someone could suggest some kind of android library or another approach that would reduce this delay.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest not use android mediaPlayer for RTSP live streaming.
  Internally Android mediaplayer uses nuplayer for RTSP streaming.
  Which has buffering mechanism for smooth playback. Following are the default values for buffering mechanism.

frameworks/av/media/libmediaplayerservice/nuplayer/RTSPSource.cpp

```
/* Playback will continue only if it has 1s of data*/
static const int kUnderflowMarkMs   =  1000;  // 1 second

/* Playback will only start once it has 3s of data*/
static const int kPrepareMarkMs     =  3000;  // 3 seconds

/*Maximum data to be bufferred*/
static const int kOverflowMarkMs    = 10000;  // 10 seconds
```

NuPlayer will continuously monitor the buffering status(every 1 second). Consider below code snippet.

```
void NuPlayer::RTSPSource::schedulePollBuffering() {
    sp<AMessage> msg = new AMessage(kWhatPollBuffering, this);
    msg->post(1000000ll); // 1 second intervals
}

void NuPlayer::RTSPSource::onPollBuffering() {
    bool prepared, underflow, overflow, startServer, finished;
     checkBuffering(&prepared, &underflow, &overflow, &startServer, &finished);

    if (prepared && mInPreparationPhase) {
        mInPreparationPhase = false;
        notifyPrepared();
    }

    if (!mInPreparationPhase && underflow) {
        startBufferingIfNecessary();
    }

    if (haveSufficientDataOnAllTracks()) {
        stopBufferingIfNecessary();
    }

    if (overflow && mHandler != NULL) {
        mHandler->pause();
    }

    if (startServer && mHandler != NULL) {
        mHandler->resume();
    }

    if (finished && mHandler != NULL) {
        mHandler->cancelAccessUnitTimeoutCheck();
    }

    schedulePollBuffering();
}
```

Anytime if it hits the underflow it will pause the playback for 1s. Which will again add 1s delay to your original delay.

```
if (!mInPreparationPhase && underflow) {
    startBufferingIfNecessary();
}
```

Playback will start only if it has enough data.

```
 if (haveSufficientDataOnAllTracks()) {
        stopBufferingIfNecessary();
    }
```

Apart from that even NuDecoder has it's own delay, every time if it is out of access-units it pauses.

To Answer your question, try to write your own rtsp source and use native media codec to decode and stream. With this approach we have attained at max 1s delay.

Refer

> frameworks/av/media/libmediaplayerservice/nuplayer/RTSPSource.cpp

for writing your own rtsp source.